# scanf in Borland C++ Builder

Tags: c++, scanf, c++builder, builder, borland-c++

I'm trying to check type of my variable with function scanf. It works fine for Dev C++(my input is int), but it doesn't using Borland. Here is what I've tried:

```
AnsiString as = Edit1->Text;
string b = as.c_str();

int testb = atoi(b.c_str());

if(scanf("%i", &testb)==1){
do sth;
}
```

Any ideas?

[edit1] moved from comment by Spektre

I have another problem. My input value should look like `xx-xx-xxxx` so it's a date.
I have to check if day, month and year are integer.
I tried like this:

```
AnsiString a = Edit1->Text;
date = a.c_str();
 if (a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(0,2).c_str()))
  && a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(3,2).c_str()))
  && a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(6,4).c_str())) )
 { 
 //do sth
 }
```

- but it check only a day. Does anyone know why? –  J. B. 20 hours ago

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean by that? What happens when you run the code you show? Have you tried running in a debugger and stepping through line by line to see what happens? And why do you assign to `testb` and then directly overwrite `the value with a `scanf` call?

Comment: Can you explain how are checking type here? You calculate `testb` and then throw away its value in scanf.

Comment: I need to check if the input value is a number or a character, because I need an integer as an input type.

Comment: To both convert a string and verify that the string is indeed an integer, use e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or if you don't have it then [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)).

Comment: Better set Edit1 input type to numeric, and use `Edit1->Text->ToInt()`

Comment: @SHR that could throw an exception (AnsiString had a bug that exceptions could not be masked by try/catch still on older compilers so I do not know if they repaired it) ... better way is check the string for 0..9 only or use atoi and then convert back to string by sprintf and compare to original string... anyway scanf is not the function he needs ...

Answer (score 1):

You are making this horribly more complicated than it should be.

`scanf()` reads from STDIN, but a GUI proces does not use STDIN for input, which is why it is not working for you.  Use `sscanf()` instead:

```
int testb;
if (sscanf(AnsiString(Edit1->Text).c_str(), "%d", &testb) == 1)
{
    // do sth ...
}
```

Alternatively, use the RTL's `TryStrToInt()` instead:

```
int testb;
if (TryStrToInt(Edit1->Text, testb))
{
    // do sth ...
}
```

As for checking a date string, you can use `sscanf()` for that:

```
int day, month, year;
if (sscanf(AnsiString(Edit1->Text).c_str(), "%2d-%2d-%4d", &day, &month, &year) == 3)
{
    // do sth ...
}
```

Or use the RTL's `TryStrToDate()`:

```
TDateTime testb;

TFormatSettings fmt = TFormatSettings::Create();
fmt.DateSeparator = '-';
fmt.ShortDateFormat = "d-m-y";

if (TryStrToDate(Edit1->Text, testb, fmt))
{
    // do sth ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way

```
AnsiString s=Edit1->Text; // copy to real AnsiString ... the AnsiStrings inside visual components are not the same ... some functions/operations does not work properly for them
int e,i,l=s.Length();

for(e=0,i=1;i<=l;) 
 {
 e=1; // assume it is integer
 if (s[i]=='-') i++; // skip first minus sign
  for (;i<=l;i++) // scan all the rest 
   if ((s[i]<'0')||(s[i]>'9')) // if not a digit
    { 
    e=0; // then not an integer
    break; // stop
    }
 break;
 }
// here e holds true/false if s is valid integer

now you can use safely
if (e) i=s.ToInt(); else i=0;
```

- not sure If `s.ToInt()` is also so buggy  but at least until BDS2006
- if you call `s.ToDouble()` for invalid number then an unmaskable exception is thrown
- so for example if you try to convert `0.98` and the decimal point is not set to `.` your program crashes (atoi and atof are safe)

you can also use sprintf:

```
AnsiString s=Edit1->Text;
if (s==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(s.c_str()))) /* valid integer */;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. It partly works. I have another problem. My input value should look like xx-xx-xxxx so it's a date. I have to check if day, month and year are integer. I tried like this:
AnsiString a = Edit1->Text;
date = a.c_str()
if(a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(0,2).c_str())) && a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(3,2).c_str()))
&& a==AnsiString().sprintf("%i",atoi(a.SubString(6,4).c_str())) ){ do sth}
but it check only a day. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @J.B. for two reasons. 1. you should add brackets for inner conditions to separate && operands (sometimes compiler do funny things with multile condition if's if not bracketed) 2. AnsiString has a little bug on older VCL (bds2006 included) that if you call `...=a.sprintf(...)`  or `...=a.SubString(...)` it also changes the a variable (for example in BCB5 this was OK but in BCB6 and BDS2006 ... its bugged) either store substrings to separate variables and cut them there after or use the first option in my answer (where you can hardcode the for with `-` skipping ... it will also look much nicer

Comment: @J.B. also check in breakpoint the value of `a.SubString(6,4)` because AnsiString indexing is from 1 not from 0 ... should not it be `a.SubString(7,4)` (not sure now and too lazy to check it)?